# Custom Domain Not working with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, domain-name

I was trying to add SSL/HTTPS support to my website on google app engine and everything broke when I added custom domains:

1) http://my-domain.com
2) http://www.my-domain.com

I added corresponding A, AAAA, and CNAME (www) information into Godaddy zone file. When I access my website, I get this error:

```
Error: Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

At this point, I have disabled ssl. I still get the problem.

**Note:** I used ghs.googlehosted.com for CNAME. The problem didn't go away.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by readding custom domain using a different google account (own account) which I used for accessing google cloud console. Previously I was trying to do add custom domain and ssl using a different google account which was added as an admin by my own account. Everything works fine after switching back to my own account.